# SignalR not call a seconf Hub Class

Tags: c#, signalr

I have 2 Hub Class in my project

```
public class FolderManager : Hub
{
  public FolderManager()
  {
  }
    public void Validator()
    {
    }
}

public class SeoContentValidator : Hub
{
    public SeoContentValidator()
    {

    }
    public void Validator()
    {
    }
}
```

I have my Start Class

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

In my view I have this script

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var folderManager = $.connection.folderManager;
    var seoContentValidator = $.connection.seoContentValidator;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
     $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        folderManager.server.validator();
        seoContentValidator.server.validator();
    });

  });
</script>
```

The problem that I have is signalR can find and call folderManager.server.validator();

But cant find seoContentValidator.server.validator();

What I am doing wrong in SeoContentValidator that signalR can not find it

Comment: I have run your code and cannot recreate the error - I have set breakpoints on both Validator() methods and both are getting hit. That is with VS2013 and the latest SignalR package. Please provide more details if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. In fact, I tried you example.
My signalr/hubs generated proxy has the following code:

```js
    proxies['folderManager'] = this.createHubProxy('folderManager'); 
    proxies['folderManager'].client = { };
    proxies['folderManager'].server = {
        validator: function () {
            return proxies['folderManager'].invoke.apply(proxies['folderManager'], $.merge(["Validator"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
         }
    };

    proxies['seoContentValidator'] = this.createHubProxy('seoContentValidator'); 
    proxies['seoContentValidator'].client = { };
    proxies['seoContentValidator'].server = {
        validator: function () {
            return proxies['seoContentValidator'].invoke.apply(proxies['seoContentValidator'], $.merge(["Validator"], $.makeArray(arguments)));
         }
    };
```

And on start my js log states:

```
    [ ... ] SignalR: Invoking foldermanager.Validator
    [ ... ] SignalR: Invoking seocontentvalidator.Validator
```

I also set breakpoints on the hub methods and ran the app in debug mode. Both the breakpoints are triggered.

Is the JS code I copied present in your generated proxy file?
You have no JS errors when running?

I assume that the example code you wrote is not your actual code. Try to debug your code, also use detailed error messages:

```cs
    public class Startup {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        }
    }
```

Wrap your hub methods in try-catch blocks, it can help a lot.

Let me know if you found the problem.